Blender Render is very slow 1-2 frames per second on Ubuntu 23.10
I am using Ubuntu 23.10 Mantic Minotaur and the blender render is 1-2 frames per second have tried everything and I have the correct drivers for all my components. I am using the current stable version in APT 3.6.2. It worked well in windows so it is not a hardware issue. Have let blender use any and all resources available through settings and cache do not know what to do. Thanks in advance!
